# Spring Security: provide access depending on service call

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

I have spring boot application which exposes REST endpoints protected by spring security.

**I need to restrict access to some paths depending on service call.** Let's say I have a service like this:

```
@Service
public class AccessService {
    boolean hasAccess(String requestedPath) {
        // some business logic here
    }
}
```

The service will check user roles, some business conditions and return `true` or `false`.

**Now I need to integrate this service call into my security configuration**.

So far I have configuration like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                ...
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
}
```

I see no way of adding the service call here (as it is completely static).

**What I'm trying:**

Currently I'm thinking of overriding my `AuthenticationProvider` and extending it with the additional functionality.

The other option would be to extend my REST controllers from a class which would do some sort of authorization, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

**Question:** How can I protect REST endpoints based on service method call? What is the proper way of doing that?

Comment: I suggest a read of [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web). Something like `anyRequest().access("@accessService.hasAccess(request.requestURI) && hasRole('USER')");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authorization.html#el-access). Basically you need to use the `access` expression instead of the `hasRole`. You can then write powerful security expressions.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
anyRequest()
    .access("@accessService.hasAccess(request.reques‌​tURI) && hasRole('USER')");
```

This restricts access to user with the role `ROLE_USER` and which have access according to your own custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to to this is to use `@PreAuthorize`
Some documentation can be found here: [Expression-Based Access Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).

You are also able to add your own evaluator class/methods to customize to your specific needs:
`@PreAuthorize("@customPermissionEvaluator.accessMethod(variable)")`

Example class:

```
@Service(value = "customPermissionEvaluator")
public class CustomPermissionEvaluatorImpl implements CustomPermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean accessMethod(int variable) {      
        if (variable == 1) {
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }
}
```